# Display tag related archicles in tag.php in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

Im working on a Wordpress web site, that has a custom post type called "success-stories". For this I have created tags, using functions.php.
I want to have a page where only a particular tag related articles can be displayed.
When I open the tag link, no error happens but no artivle is displayed so far. 
What should I do?

functions.php

```
function reg_tag() {
     register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'success-stories');
}
add_action('init', 'reg_tag');
```

tag.php

```
<?php
 $query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
 if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

 //terms
 $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'success-storiescat');
 $nameTerm = $terms[0]->name;

?>
```